# Windows 10: Open settings apps by Powershell (fx. logon settings)

Tags: windows, powershell

How do I open the setting Apps in windows 10 using Powershell?
I know I can open a controlpanel-item using:

> control.exe /name Microsoft.WindowsUpdate

which opens the Windows Update App.

But I can't find info for opening the "Settings for Logon" app - where I want users to be directed to, for configuring Windows Hello-Fingertouch identification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some URI's available.
Look at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app

You can invoke them easily in PS, especially for your case:

```bsh
Start-Process ms-settings:signinoptions
```

Another Example for Mouse Settings:

```bsh
Start-Process ms-settings:easeofaccess-mouse
```

Or just the entry point for the Settings (if no other settings page is still open):

```bsh
Start-Process ms-settings:
```